# im trying to clone a part that gives points and put in a random X axis but it spawns in the same position

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local randomnumber = math.random(18,45)

while true do
    wait(1)
    local Pointgiver = game.ReplicatedStorage.Points:Clone()
    Pointgiver.Parent = game.Workspace
    Pointgiver.Position = Vector3.new(randomnumber,0.5,-0.6)
    Pointgiver.Transparency = 0
end
```

doesnt give any errors but it spawns in the same position, help me

Answer (score 0):

That's because you generate the random number outside of the loop.

[image: random number]

---

Fix: Move `local randomnumber = math.random(18,45)` into the loop:

```lua
while true do
    wait(1)
    local Pointgiver = game.ReplicatedStorage.Points:Clone()
    Pointgiver.Parent = game.Workspace
    local randomnumber = math.random(18,45)
    Pointgiver.Position = Vector3.new(randomnumber,0.5,-0.6)
    Pointgiver.Transparency = 0
end
```

I suggest you to revise the core programming concepts of control flow / order of execution.